# ember liquid-tether modals

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I am using - http://pzuraq.github.io/liquid-tether/#/examples?a=hello-world

Scroll down to 'Animation With Context'. i have put the code in as on these pages.

I get the error: gte is not defined.

template.hbs

```
<div class="example-button-container">
  <button {{action "openModalDialog"}}>
    Open Dialog
  </button>
</div>

{{#if showFirstModalDialog}}
  {{#liquid-tether
    to="modal-dialog"
    target="document.body"
    targetModifier="visible"
    attachment="middle center"
    tetherClass="modal-dialog"
    overlayClass="modal-backdrop"}}
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
      </div>

      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Here's a modal!</p>
      </div>

      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button {{action "closeModalDialog"}}>Cancel</button>
        <button {{action "nextModalDialog"}}>Next</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  {{/liquid-tether}}
{{/if}}

{{#if showSecondModalDialog}}
  {{#liquid-tether
    to="modal-dialog"
    target="document.body"
    targetModifier="visible"
    attachment="middle center"
    tetherClass="modal-dialog"
    overlayClass="modal-backdrop"}}
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title">Another Modal</h4>
      </div>

      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>
          This modal came in from the right instead of fading. The next modal
          will also slide in from the right, while the previous modal will slide
          in from the left, maintaing spacial context.
        </p>
      </div>

      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button {{action "prevModalDialog"}}>Back</button>
        <button {{action "nextModalDialog"}}>Next</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  {{/liquid-tether}}
{{/if}}

{{#if showThirdModalDialog}}
  {{#liquid-tether
    to="modal-dialog"
    target="document.body"
    targetModifier="visible"
    attachment="middle center"
    tetherClass="modal-dialog"
    overlayClass="modal-backdrop"}}
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title">Another Modal</h4>
      </div>

      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>
          This is the last modal! It'll fade out when you finish the dialog.
        </p>
      </div>

      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button {{action "prevModalDialog"}}>Back</button>
        <button {{action "closeModalDialog"}}>Finish</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  {{/liquid-tether}}
{{/if}}
```

mycontroller.js

```
export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  showFirstModalDialog: gte('currentModalDialogStep', 1),
  showSecondModalDialog: gte('currentModalDialogStep', 2),
  showThirdModalDialog: gte('currentModalDialogStep', 3),

  actions: {
    openModalDialog() {
      this.set('currentModalDialogStep', 1);
    },

    prevModalDialog() {
      this.decrementProperty('currentModalDialogStep');
    },

    nextModalDialog() {
      this.incrementProperty('currentModalDialogStep');
    },

    closeModalDialog() {
      this.set('currentModalDialogStep', 0);
    }
  }
});
```

mytransitions.js:

```
this.transition(
  target('modal-dialog'),
  this.toValue(({ index: newIndex }, { index: oldIndex }) => newIndex > oldIndex),
  this.use('tether', ['to-left', options]),
  this.reverse('tether', ['to-right', options])
);

this.transition(
  target('modal-dialog'),
  this.toValue(({ index }) => index === 1),
  this.use('tether', 'fade', 'fade')
);

this.transition(
  target('modal-dialog'),
  this.toValue(({ index }) => !index),
  this.use('tether', 'fade', 'fade')
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Didn't you forget to import `Ember.computed.gte`?

```
import Ember from 'ember';
const gte = Ember.computed.gte;  

export default Ember.Controller.extend({
      showFirstModalDialog: gte('currentModalDialogStep', 1),
      showSecondModalDialog: gte('currentModalDialogStep', 2),
      showThirdModalDialog: gte('currentModalDialogStep', 3),

      actions: {
        openModalDialog() {
          this.set('currentModalDialogStep', 1);
        },

        prevModalDialog() {
          this.decrementProperty('currentModalDialogStep');
        },

        nextModalDialog() {
          this.incrementProperty('currentModalDialogStep');
        },

        closeModalDialog() {
          this.set('currentModalDialogStep', 0);
        }
      }
    });
```

Comment: now the error is gone, but I get a black page and not a modal display. Any ideas? Many thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't have experience with this addon, however, I would start looking at the console (any error output?), inspecting the DOM (is the modal block present or not? Is CSS fine?)..

Comment: there wasn't any errors. i used google chrome/developer tools, and after expanding loads of divs found he backdrop z-index was overlapping the modal! ....voted your comment as helpful for your effort :-)